# Purpose of two-way encryption of JWE

Tags: encryption, rsa, json

If we look at encryption format and standards of JWE following [RFC-7516](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516), we can see that it uses a 2 way encryption method.

So what are the benefits of this compared to just using RSA? Are computation (decryption) time not significantly affected?

Answer (score 1):

## JWT supports RSA encryption

I'm not familiar with the term "2 way encryption", but I assume you mean symmetric encryption (AES).

The JWE spec does support RSA encryption, it's just not that commonly-used, for reasons I'll describe below.

From RFC 7516 that you linked to -- [section 3.3 Example JWE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516#section-3.3)

> The Content Encryption Key is encrypted to the recipient using the
> RSAES-OAEP [RFC3447] algorithm to produce the JWE Encrypted Key.

And if you click through to RFC 7518 which defines the list of crypto algorithms supported by JWE, you see that there are two RSA-based encryption methods available for JWE:

> - 4.2.  Key Encryption with RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5
> - 4.3.  Key Encryption with RSAES OAEP

---

## Why do you never see JWEs with RSA encryption?

RSA can only encrypt messages up to (roughly) the size of the RSA key. For example RSA 2048 can encrypt up to about 2048 bits (256 bytes, actually a bit less depending on padding scheme). JWTs are often longer than 256 bytes. So when you say "encrypting with RSA" what you usually mean is a hybrid mode where you encrypt the content with AES and then encrypt the AES key with RSA. The reason to add the extra RSA layer around AES is where you want to encrypt for a different person; for example Alice wants to encrypt a message for Bob, but Alice does not know Bob's private key.

In all of the webapps that I've seen where the contents of the JWT are sensitive and need to be encrypted, the server that creates the JWT is also the one that consumes it. Basically, the server is asking the user to hold on to the JWE and hand it back later. In this case you can just use AES without the extra RSA layer because you are encrypting for yourself. As mentioned above, if you have a case where the server generating the JWT is different from the one consuming it, and the contents are sensitive and need to be encrypted, the JWE spec does support RSA-based encryption.